# SSRS Custom number format to display zero percent as hypen

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2012

I have an extensive report that contains mostly integers and decimals with a few percentage columns. The integers and decimals are set under the Number format to display zero as " - ".

Unfortunately the percentage number format has no extra formatting options besides adding a space between the number and the percent symbol.

I can't work out a custom number format that will replace any instances of zero in the column, currently shown as 0.00% with - instead, to match the rest of the report. It's making it look a bit messy. (Pic shows the fields highlighted that I would like to show as - instead.)

[image: SSRS Zero Percent Examples]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the value of those cells to an expression which checks for and replaces a 0 with a hyphen.

```
=IIf(Fields!MarginNB.Value = 0, "-", Fields!MarginNB.Value)
```

Comment: I've undone what I was originally going to comment, I've managed to get this to work with the custom code that's calculating the first two columns and not ruin my variance column. Thank you, can't believe it was that simple!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this whilst looking for something else.

In the Cell Format box type 0.00%;-0.00%;'-'